# Use transistors to amplify a very small voltage

Tags: led, transistors

I'm new to electronics and I have a problem. I want to use a LED to detect light but the voltage it provides is very small (30 mV) and I don't think it can open a transistor. How can I amplify this voltage? (I don't want to use op amp) And, I have only NPN transistors. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you know how to select and fix a bias point for the transistor?

Comment: I'm new to this and i don't think i ever heard about bias (sory form my mistakes,this is not my original language)

Comment: You probably need two transistors, arranged so that the base-emitter voltages cancel out. Read up on "long tailed pair".

Comment: Why use an LED for light detection? There are much better devices.

Comment: I can't find any photo diodes here and i don't have time to buy one from internet and leds are very good at that but the voltage is too small.

Comment: Can't you find an LDR/photocell?

Comment: This is a good example of a good question but somebody has down-voted it.

Comment: @Dwayne: I didn't do the downvote, but I can see how the *"I don't want to use op amp"* statement may be deserving of one, not to mention lower case *"i"* in several places and *"Can you help me?"*, making the correct answer to the question simply "Yes". Using a opamp is the obvious simple way to do this. Since the OP gave no justification, this smells like a religious issue, probably because the OP doesn't know how to use opamps. Not knowing opamps is OK, but wanting to avoid learning about them is not, at least not here.  The more I think about it, the more I'm inclined to -1 too.

Comment: I agree. Please justify why the obvious op-amp solution is impractical for you. Saying that you haven't got one is not a reasonable answer. Requesting a cure for a bacterial infection by means other than antibiotics would also raise alarms. Please justify.

Comment: First of all: THIS IS NOT MY ORIGINAL LANGUAGE.And if I used several times "I" that means that I know why, am I right? So those "lower cases" are only mistakes, right? Everything is logic. And in my country it sounds terrible to say only what you WANT WITHOUT the permision of that person,am I right? This is about education so it's your "teritory". And I'm 13 years old so I CAN'T buy anything from the internet!

Comment: Note that instead of using the LED like a solar cell to generate a voltage, you can also apply a reverse voltage (say 3V) to the LED, and use it like a photo diode.  In that case, rather than a voltage, you will get a current proportional to the incident light.  The current would typically be on the order of micro amps.  By using a suitably high series resistor (hundreds of kilo ohms, or mega-ohms) that current could be turned into a voltage that might be even as high as a couple of volts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to detect light then use this circuit.  Reverse bias the LED into the emitter of an NPN transistor.  When light hits the LED then reverse current will flow proportional to the incident light.  The transistor provides current gain, boosting the LED current from say (10uA) to around 1mA.

The behavior of the circuit will be this.
In the dark the output is high, in the light the output is low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCTaeQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the LED (photodiode) is a current source, and you avoid op amps and provide a circuit using an NPN transistor as requested :) If the OP only had MOSFETs on hand instead of bipolar transistors, the photocurrent could be turned into a gate voltage via a resistor.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want if you add some amplification to the output signal from the LED.  A single op-amp can do this or you can use a pair of transistors configured as a differential amplifier (the "long-tailed pair" that Brian Drummond mentions above.

I'm going to show you an op-amp version because it is easy.  I like using the LM358 or LM324 op-amps for these simple circuits - they are readily available and the input common-mode voltage range includes ground.  That makes them easy to use with a single supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIxsNa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Upon rereading your question, I see that you asked if you could do this using only NPN transistors.  Probably yes but it's not either easy or obvious.  The problem is that the signal provided by the LED is both low voltage and very high impedance - some of the references that I checked show the LED being loaded by a very high value resistor (30M or 100M).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with just NPN transistors. 60mV is small, but probably enough.
Resistor values will depend on your voltage source, but try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL9ZQi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In normal conditions, R1 and R2 set Base voltage about 0.57V - not quite enough to conduct. Adding 30mV gets you 0.6V. With no Emitter resistor, you should get a decent current through R3.

You can also look at "super alpha" designs for very high gain. One example is [here](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/TouchSwitch/images/touchswtr.gif)

**EDIT**:  there should be another resistor (RD) in series with D1. Just as R1/R2 bias the transistor in cutoff, RD would limit the voltage across, and current through, D1.
The last time I built this circuit, many years ago, I used a Light Dependenet Resistor (LDR) instead of a diode. LDR's have a resistance of Mega ohms in dark, dropping to about 10K in bright light, so voltage across them is not as big an issue. The same can't be said for diodes.

Comment: @ Alan Campbell: if you have a chance, why don't you try breadboarding this?  After you have replaced the LED and transistor because they burned up, maybe you can come up with something different.  Please note: I'm not trying to be sarcastic or mean.  It's just that what you have drawn can't possibly work and it's not fair to the original poster to suggest your circuit.  Please also note that I'm not down-voting your answer - I'd genuinely like you to have a look at it and improve it.

Comment: You're right - I wish I had a breadboard. I'd also like to re-design the base bias [as it stands, the diode has it turned on hard].

Comment: I'm not sure what the on-state voltage of this LED is but it looks like you have a path from 5V through the emitter of the transistor and then to ground.  I suspect this circuit would burn up the LED, transistor, or both.

Comment: user4574 yes - that's why I edited the post to say there should be another resistor in series with the diode. The value of the resistor depends on the voltage drop across the LED, which I have seen vary from 1.6V (red) to over 3.2V (blue).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use an LED (not good but cheap) you should probably use it as a current device and make a one op-amp current-to-voltage converter.  Very simple and the output would be linear.  Use a TL061 for its low cost and its low bias current which might be important depending on the amount of current the LED puts out.  Do not use a TI brand TLO61 which has given me problems in years past.

Comment: OP said he doesn't want to use an op amp...

Comment: bad choice on his part

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the LED is a current source in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with something that *might* work.  You will need to breadboard it and see.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flidGj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 & Q2 need to be identical transistors, preferably from the same batch.  They should also be touching each other if possible so that they are at exactly the same temperature.

Cover D1 and adjust R1 so that the output LED (D2) goes out.  Then shine light at D1 and see if D2 lights up.

No guarantees that this works but it should.  I'm not anywhere near my lab bench, so I can't try it myself.

Comment: Q3 is PNP. OP requests NPN only.